# option menu on Listview

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` on my Android application and I want to add option menu with pushing button on the right side of `Listview`: "Edit" and "Remove". I posted screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Create custom layout for your list view row and create class which extends BaseAdapter class.

Answer (score 3):

First create a menu.xml file in **/drawable/menu/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:title="One" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Two" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="Three" />
</menu>
```

Declare

```
private PopupMenu popup;
```

Now in your list view {your menu dots icon} .setonClickListener method

```
popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();          
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
             @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                     switch (item.getItemId()) {

                                 case R.id.one:

                                        break;

                                 case R.id.two:

                                        break;

                                 case R.id.three:

                                        break;

                            }
                    return false;
                    }
    });
```